# Output by sorting is Wrong

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I want to sort this Array but the output is Wrong . It sorts not increasing with "False".

it works when I change the number

Could someone explain it me?

```
prices = [{ 'price': '9.87940000'}, { 'price': '9.94400000'}, {'price': '10.33820000'}, {'price': '10.73820000'}]

prices_sorted = sorted(prices, key=lambda x: x['price'], reverse=False)
for prices in  prices_sorted :
    print(prices)


The output :
{'price': '10.33820000'}
{'price': '10.73820000'}
{'price': '9.87940000'}
{'price': '9.94400000'}

Two wrongs : 10.33820000 < 10.73820000 and not increasing with "False"

by anpther number it works 
prices = [{ 'price': '5.87940000'}, { 'price': '6.94400000'}, {'price': '7.33820000'}, {'price': '8.73820000'}]

prices_sorted = sorted(prices, key=lambda x: x['price'], reverse=False)

for prices in  prices_sorted :
    print(prices)

The output :
{'price': '5.87940000'}
{'price': '6.94400000'}
{'price': '7.33820000'}
{'price': '8.73820000'}
```

Comment: In your `key=` function convert the string to float: `key=lambda x: float(x["price"])`

Comment: You have sorted some strings into alphabetical order.  There are no *numbers* anywhere in your program.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are encountering is due to the fact that the prices are treated here as strings and not numbers, when it is being sorted.

prices = [{'price': 9.87940000}, {'price': 9.94400000}, {'price': 10.33820000}, {'price': 10.73820000}]

----Sort the list of dictionaries based on the 'price' key
prices_sorted = sorted(prices, key=lambda x: x['price'], reverse=False)

----Print the sorted list of dictionaries
for price in prices_sorted:
print(price)